# Using delegate to update UIPageControl

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I have a simple UIPageViewController with the entire thing done programatically. The page view controller is working. However, I cannot update the Page Control which is in the main/parent view controller.

Here is my Page View Controller:

```
protocol PageControlUpdate {
    func updatePage(current index : Int)
}

class IntroPageViewC: UIPageViewController {


    var updatePageDelegate : PageControlUpdate?



// other delegate methods

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if completed {

            updatePageDelegate?.updatePage(current: currentIndex)
}
}
```

And then in the main view controller:

```
var introPageControl = UIPageControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        introPageControl.delegate = self
        introPageControl.tintColor = .systemRed
        introPageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        introPageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.green
        allViews.append(introPageControl)
}

func updatePage(current index: Int) {
        introPageControl.currentPage = index // this is the UI page control

    }
```

I am not getting the index value in the main view controller. I tried setting:
introPageControl.delegate = self but then I get an error saying introPageControl does not have a delegate member

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
[image]

**EDIT:**
I tried to declare the delegate to the class and got this error where PickupViewController is the parent view controller

[image]

Comment: post code where you set `introPageControl.delegate = self`

Comment: without setting `introPageControl.delegate = self` your `updatePageDelegate` remains nil ... so you have to set that to self

Comment: I updated the code to indicate that I did add the line and when I do, I get the error included in the screenshot. Still not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you are using `UIPageControl()` instead of  `IntroPageViewC`

Comment: Where exactly would I specify that? When I declare var introPageControl = UIPageControl() ? Sorry, I dont understand. Still learning.

Comment: did you try to declare introPageControl = UIPageControl() in vieDidLoad? then delegate?

Comment: where you are using `IntroPageViewC`?

Comment: No, I declared introPageControl just before the viewDidLoad() function and INSIDE the viewDidLoad() I tried to assign the delegate i.e. introPageContro.delegate = self

Comment: IntroPageViewC is the subclass of the UIPageViewController. That is where I declare the delegate and call it. Please see the first block of code I posted. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Aah I think I see what you are saying jawadAli. I need to declare the delegate on the subclass of the UIPageViewController which is IntroPageViewC and not the introPageControl which is a UIPageControl. If so, how would I go about doing that?